# How can I start an application at start up as a different user?

Tags: startup, services, non-root-user

I am trying to start an application in Linux at start up with a different user (like alpha). I want it to run it in the background and it has to be started with with parameters.

One is a file system and other is an application so first file system should start then the application should start with parameters.

I tried to use crontab @ reboot but is it possible to use init.d?

Comment: What disro and init system do you use? It sounds like you may be an a `SysVInit` system. Which one? Does in matter where these items start up in relation to the rest of the system? Do they need to be monitored and restarted if they fail or just launched once on startup?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "file system should start"? Anyway, the best option would be probably this one:

- Define what you want to launch: `su alpha -c "/path/of/app parm1 parm2 &"` (define user after `su` to login as such and then use `&` to run it in the background).
- Add command to your `/etc/rc.conf` so it starts on boot.